# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php

Hallo

I have this script:

```
<?
  require("lib2/config.inc.php");
  require("lib2/tpl.class.php");
  require("lib2/db.class.php");
  require("lib2/um.class.php");


  $tpl          = new template("templates", "tpl");
  $db         = new db($db['location'], $db['username'], $db['passwort'], $db['database']);
  $um         = new usermanagment();


  /** User login **/

  $checklogin       = $um->check_login();
  $userdata       = $um->getuserdata();

  if(!$checklogin && !$guest) {
    header("LOCATION: ./index2.php");
  }

  eval("\$header .= \" ".$tpl->get("header")."\";");
  eval("\$footer .= \" ".$tpl->get("footer")."\";");

$time     = time();
$db->Query("UPDATE userdaten SET lastaction = '$time' WHERE userid = '".$userdata['userid']."'");
?>
```

And get this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/httpd/html/login/global.php(22) : eval()'d code on line 96

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` here at all? It's completely unnecessary. Usually it just needlessly opens you up to code injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first look you ... the error is probably in the code passed to the function eval().

**Note:** I do not use the function eval(). It can cause hidden mistakes, which are difficult to find.